# Einstein Analytics dashboard automatic download of snapshot

Tags: dashboard, einstein-analytics, einstein, analytic-snapshots, snapshot

Is it possible to automatically generate a pdf/jpeg file in analytics dashboard.
Can it be done using salesforce standard or custom(Apex).

Comment: I'm also looking for such option. You found yourself a solution?